# Problem creating basic nativescript app on a mac

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I'm following the extreme beginner course on this video

```
https://courses.nativescripting.com/courses/169856/lectures/6887491
```

I have after creating the app run a npm install on the source code, but when I run the command

```
tns run ios
```

it opens an ipad emulator but there is nothing in it and there is an error in the terminal

```
Executing webpack failed with exit code 1.
```

Has anyone got any clues?

thanks

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn on emulators before you do `tns run xx`, also run `tns devices` before to see are they are all visible, emulators and connected devices. Then do `tns run xx`. Also i hope you did `tns doctor` before all this to see is all in order.

Just spent couple of days setting it myself on Big Sur. It works well (xcode simulator ios and android emulators via android studio, and android device over usb) but some things you will need to figure out yourself, don't rely to much on articles, things change rapidly as it seems to me.

Also for some reason like you noticed `tns run ios` will allwyas try to run iPad, so you save your self a working iPhone simulator in dock, and just turn on that before you do `tns run`.