# NativeScript cannot launch iOS emulator

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular, nativescript-plugin, nativescript-telerik-ui

Emulator started when I run `ns run ios` However, app cannot be deployed with the following error:

```
Unable to apply changes on device: D2B97EAA-B6DB-4920-8974-4F615FEB4E82. Error is: Command xcrun with arguments simctl install D2B97EAA-B6DB-4920-8974-4F615FEB4E82 /Users/cupidchan/Documents/GitHub/pistevo-health/NativeScript/platforms/ios/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/NativeScript.app failed with exit code 1. Error output:
 An error was encountered processing the command (domain=IXUserPresentableErrorDomain, code=1):
Unable To Install “NativeScript”
Please try again later.
The parent bundle has the same identifier (org.nativescript.NativeScript) as sub-bundle at /Users/cupidchan/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/D2B97EAA-B6DB-4920-8974-4F615FEB4E82/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.ammMqk/extracted/NativeScript.app/Frameworks/NativeScript.framework
Underlying error (domain=MIInstallerErrorDomain, code=57):
        The parent bundle has the same identifier (org.nativescript.NativeScript) as sub-bundle at /Users/cupidchan/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/D2B97EAA-B6DB-4920-8974-4F615FEB4E82/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.ammMqk/extracted/NativeScript.app/Frameworks/NativeScript.framework
```

**Environment**
NativeScript: 8.0.1,
Xcode: 12.4,
iOS 14.4

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Problem creating basic nativescript app on a mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66671994/problem-creating-basic-nativescript-app-on-a-mac)

Answer (score 0):

I have found out that this is because of the appid of the NativeScript. When I created the application using `ns create myapp`, I didn't specify `--appid` parameter. Hence NativeScript created one for me. However, you can change this id in `./nativescript.config.ts` After you name with something unique to your app, it can start the emulator correctly.